conda deep tempest dependencies fail to load
i try to create my environment  using the requirements.txt file as is laid out in the readme file for setting up deep tempest (https://github.com/emidan19/deep-tempest)
conda create --name deeptempest --file requirements.txt
Channels:
 - main
 - fastchan
 - nvidia
 - pytorch
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyqtwebengine==5.12.1=pypi_0
  - pyqtchart==5.12=pypi_0
  - pyqt5-sip==4.19.18=pypi_0
  - pybind11==2.11.1=pypi_0
  - numba==0.56.4=np1.16py3.9h59fbc97_g288a38bbd_0
  - llvmlite==0.39.1=py39he1b5a44_0
  - fastwer==0.1.3=pypi_0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/main
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/fastchan
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

conda tells me im missing packages and theyre not available in my current channels despite the fact that they are available in my current channels
conda install fastchan::pyqtwebengine
Channels:
 - main
 - fastchan
 - nvidia
 - pytorch
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

obviously ive tried installing the missing packages but it either tells me theyre already installed or i cant even find the package on anaconda.org at all i.e (fastwer)

I parsed the Python files and here is a list a of modules that are imported that are not in the standard library:
cv2
doxyxml
einops
fastwer
gnuradio
gnuradio-pmt
hdf5storage
joblib
lmdb
mat
matplotlib
numba
numpy
optuna
pandas
pillow
pyqt
pytesseract
scipy
six
skimage
sklearn
torch
torchvision
tqdm

It looks like the author just dumped their entire environment without thinking if all the packages are really necessary.  You can try removing the build pinning (everything after the second equal sign) and possibly the patch number from the requirements.
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
alembic=1.8.1
appdirs=1.4.4
blas=1.0
blosc=1.21.3
brotli=1.0.9
brotli-bin=1.0.9
brotlipy=0.7.0
brunsli=0.1
bzip2=1.0.8
c-ares=1.19.0
cairo=1.16.0
certifi=2023.7.22
cffi=1.15.1
cfitsio=3.470
charls=2.2.0
charset-normalizer=2.0.4
cloudpickle=2.0.0
cmaes=0.10.0
colorama=0.4.6
colorlog=6.7.0
contourpy=1.0.5
cryptography=39.0.1
cuda-cudart=11.8.89
cuda-cupti=11.8.87
cuda-libraries=11.8.0
cuda-nvrtc=11.8.89
cuda-nvtx=11.8.86
cuda-runtime=11.8.0
cycler=0.11.0
cytoolz=0.12.0
dask-core=2022.7.0
dbus=1.13.18
expat=2.4.9
fastwer=0.1.3
ffmpeg=4.3.2
filelock=3.9.0
flit-core=3.8.0
fontconfig=2.13.1
fonttools=4.25.0
freetype=2.12.1
fsspec=2023.3.0
gettext=0.19.8.1
giflib=5.2.1
glib=2.68.4
glib-tools=2.68.4
gmp=6.2.1
gmpy2=2.1.2
gnutls=3.6.15
graphite2=1.3.13
gst-plugins-base=1.14.5
gstreamer=1.18.5
harfbuzz=2.9.1
hdf5=1.12.1
icu=68.2
idna=3.4
imagecodecs=2021.8.26
imageio=2.26.0
importlib-metadata=6.8.0
importlib_resources=5.2.0
intel-openmp=2021.4.0
jasper=1.900.1
jinja2=3.1.2
joblib=1.2.0
jpeg=9e=h5eee18b_1
jxrlib=1.1
kiwisolver=1.4.4
krb5=1.19.4
lame=3.100
lcms2=2.12
ld_impl_linux-64=2.38
leptonica=1.78.0
lerc=3.0
libaec=1.0.4
libarchive=3.4.2
libblas=3.9.0
libbrotlicommon=1.0.9
libbrotlidec=1.0.9
libbrotlienc=1.0.9
libcblas=3.9.0
libclang=11.1.0
libcublas=11.11.3.6
libcufft=10.9.0.58
libcufile=1.6.0.25
libcurand=10.3.2.56
libcurl=7.88.1
libcusolver=11.4.1.48
libcusparse=11.7.5.86
libdeflate=1.8
libedit=3.1.20221030
libev=4.33
libevent=2.1.10
libffi=3.4.2
libgcc-ng=11.2.0
libgfortran-ng=11.2.0
libgfortran5=11.2.0
libglib=2.68.4
libgomp=11.2.0
libiconv=1.16
libidn2=2.3.2
liblapack=3.9.0
liblapacke=3.9.0
libllvm10=10.0.1
libllvm11=11.1.0
libnghttp2=1.46.0
libnpp=11.8.0.86
libnvjpeg=11.9.0.86
libopencv=4.5.3
libpng=1.6.39
libpq=12.9
libprotobuf=3.16.0
libssh2=1.10.0
libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0
libtasn1=4.16.0
libtiff=4.4.0
libunistring=0.9.10
libuuid=1.41.5
libwebp=1.2.4
libwebp-base=1.2.4
libxcb=1.15
libxkbcommon=1.0.3
libxml2=2.9.12
libzopfli=1.0.3
llvmlite=0.39.1
lmdb=0.9.29
locket=1.0.0
lz4-c=1.9.4
mako=1.2.4
markupsafe=2.1.1
matplotlib=3.7.1
matplotlib-base=3.7.1
mkl=2021.4.0
mkl-service=2.4.0
mkl_fft=1.3.1
mkl_random=1.2.2
mpc=1.1.0
mpfr=4.0.2
mpmath=1.2.1
munkres=1.1.4
mysql-common=8.0.25
mysql-libs=8.0.25
ncurses=6.4
nettle=3.7.3
networkx=2.8.4
ninja=1.10.2
ninja-base=1.10.2
nspr=4.33
nss=3.74
numba=0.56.4
numpy=1.23.5
numpy-base=1.23.5
opencv=4.5.3
openh264=2.1.1
openjpeg=2.4.0
openssl
optuna=3.2.0
packaging=23.0
partd=1.2.0
pcre=8.45
pillow=9.4.0
pip=23.0.1
pixman=0.40.0
plotly=5.9.0
ply=3.11
pooch=1.4.0
py-opencv=4.5.3
pybind11=2.11.1
pycparser=2.21
pyopenssl=23.0.0
pyparsing=3.0.9
pyqt=5.12.3
pyqt5-sip=4.19.18
pyqtchart=5.12
pyqtwebengine=5.12.1
pysocks=1.7.1
pytesseract=0.3.10
python=3.9.16
python-dateutil=2.8.2
python_abi=3.9
pytorch=2.0.0
pytorch-cuda=11.8
pytorch-mutex=1.0
pywavelets=1.4.1
pyyaml=6.0
qt=5.12.9
readline=8.2
requests=2.28.1
scikit-image=0.19.3
scikit-learn=1.2.2
scipy=1.10.0
setuptools=65.6.3
sip=6.6.2
six=1.16.0
snappy=1.1.9
sqlalchemy=1.3.24
sqlite=3.41.1
sympy=1.11.1
tenacity=8.2.2
tesseract=4.1.1
threadpoolctl=2.2.0
tifffile=2021.7.2
tk=8.6.12
toml=0.10.2
toolz=0.12.0
torchaudio=2.0.0
torchtriton=2.0.0
torchvision=0.15.0
tornado=6.2
tqdm=4.65.0
typing_extensions=4.4.0
tzdata
urllib3=1.26.14
wheel=0.38.4
x264=1!161.3030
xz=5.2.10
yaml=0.2.5
zfp=0.5.5
zipp=3.11.0
zlib=1.2.13
zstd=1.5.2

